# Make Multiple Eloquent Relationship & there's A Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Now I have news category,news, and news image table structure like : [image]

and i want to make a list like : [image]

**how i make list like that with eloquent relationship ( whereHas or Has ) ?**

PS: Sometimes news have'nt an image

Comment: you want to load images that have `cover = 1` or limit news to only those, which have related images with `cover = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your model is called `Category` and has a relationship called `news` which further has a relationship called `image`, you'd simply do the following.

```
$categories = Category::with(['news', 'news.image'])->all();
```

That would grab all categories with their news, and the image relationship if they have one.

if you don't have the relationships setup, it'd look something like this.

Category model:

```
<?php
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'category';

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('News');
    }
}
```

News model:

```
<?php
class News extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'news_main';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('NewsImage');
    }
}
```

News Image model:

```
<?php
class NewsImage extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'news_img';

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('News', 'id_news');
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

It may be worth changing the names of the tables and some of the fields to have a more uniform and sensible feel to the naming structure.

- `categories` `category_id`
- `news` `news_id`
- `news_images`

Comment: Nice , but i need to call onlye iamge with cover value = 1

Comment: `$categories = Category::with(array('news', 'news.image' => function($q)
 {
  $q->where('cover', 1);
 }))->get();`

Comment: $categories = Category::with(array('news', 'news.image' => function($q)  {   $q->where('cover', 1);  }))->get(); 
with this query , can i get all news where have image and news where have n't image ?